# If $x^2 y^5 z$ is exactly divisible by 9, what is the least value of $(x+y+z)$?

Tags: divisibility

I did find the solution on Internet [here](https://brainly.in/question/9011340).

But I am not able to understand it completely.

Comment: It doesn't say that $x,y,z$ are integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm... $x=3$, $y = z = 1$ so $(x + y + z) = 5$.  (Alternatively, $x=1$, $y=3$ and $z=1$.)

We can derive this from $x^2 y^5 z = 3^2$ and obvious logic and the prime number theorem (unique prime factorization of integers).  Specifically, the right-hand-side has a factorization of $3^2 k$ for some unknown $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.  Thus by the prime number theorem the left-hand-side *must* have a factor of the form $3^2$.  This can be achieved with $x=3$, or $y=3$ or $z = 9$ (having the smallest candidate contributions to $x+y+z$).  Can you continue?

---

If negative integers are allowed—and they shouldn't be—well then we can make as large a negative number as we want by letting $x = (-9)^{2q+1}$ for $q \to \infty$ and $q \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

If $\{ x, y, z\} \in \mathbb{R}^+$—and they shouldn't be—then we confront the possibility of $x = z = 1$ and $y^5 = 3^2$ or $y = 3^{2/5} \approx 1.55185$, so $x + y + z = 3.55185$.

Comment: $x=-3$ and $y=z=-1$ makes the sum even smaller.

Comment: Negative numbers allowed?  Then $x^2 = (-9)^{2 k}$ where $k \to \infty$.

Comment: Are they forbidden somewhere? ;)

Comment: Even if $x,y,z$ are required to be non-negative integers, we can take $x=y=z=0$.

Comment: What you (implcitly) use is not normally called the "prime number theorem". Given the OP's difficulty understanding, an answer should be much more explicit with justification.